# Is there a way how commit IDs relative to HEAD?

Tags: git, git-log

I was wondering if there's a way to list commit IDs as relative to HEAD, instead of SHA1 sum, with `git log`. For example, as `@~1`, `@~2`, `@^2` and so forth? Not that it's a big deal figuring this out manually, but it'd be nifty if git already displays this.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [tweet this morning](https://twitter.com/BestGit/status/669035642911780864) mentioning 
[list offsets from HEAD with git log](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/15063/list-offsets-from-head-with-git-log.)

```
git log --oneline | nl -v0 | sed 's/^ \+/&HEAD~/'
# or
o=0; git log --oneline | while read l; do printf "%+9s %s\n" "HEAD~${o}" "$l"; o=$(($o+1)); done | less
```

Basically, there is no native way of "decorating" a `git log` with that particular format.
You are left with `bash` to transform the output.